# Excel/GoogleSheets Forumla to List All Rows Without A Corresponding Value in Another Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I'm hoping there is a simple way to perform the following. I have 2 columns (A,B), and I would like a third column (C) which consists of all values from column A that have an empty cell in column B. I do not want column C to have spaces between each row, and it should update automatically when I add or remove values from columns A and B.

For example:

```
A          B             C
red        x             blue
blue                     yellow
pink       x             white
yellow
green      x
black      x
white
gray       x
```

Is this something that can easily be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the trick for Excel 365 at least. It relies on the `FILTER` function, which is a dynamic array function that spills into neighboring cells. The `FILTER` function is relatively new.

The below formula is entered into cell C2:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A11,B2:B11=""))`

and the result is below.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | x | blue |
| blue |  | yellow |
| pink | x | white |
| yellow |  |  |
| green | x |  |
| black | x |  |
| white |  |  |
| gray | x |  |
| blue |  |  |
| yellow |  |  |

For handling dynamic modification of the table, you can format A:B as a Table and use [structured references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e) in the formula for C2. In the below example, I used the default "Table1" for the table name. Note that column C is not part of the table; if it were, then the formula would be repeated for each row of C and you'd get `#SPILL!` errors.

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[A],Table1[B]=""))`

If you need to reference the results from the C2 formula elsewhere, you can use `=C2#`. You can also of course create a [Named Range](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) for C2 and use that named range instead. I.e., name C2 `FilteredData` and reference it elsewhere via `=FilteredData#`.